# Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier, but only when tapping search

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am having an issue with a UITableView Cell: "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier textCell", which I know is a common error, and I have read several of the entries here. The odd thing is, it works when I first draw the table. It does not fail until the user taps the search bar. I have checked the data at when the cell is being dequeued, and the various variables are populated, so the data is there.

I am using storyboards, so I should not need to register the cell, which is one of the common answers I have seen. Again, this is supported by the fact that the cell draw correctly at first. I was originally using dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:), but I also tried dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:), to no avail.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let ident = idList[indexPath.row]
    var entryText = db.getText(ident)
    let entryDate = db.getDateTimeLong(ident)
    let comments = db.getComments(ident)

    ...

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCell", for: indexPath) as? TextTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("NO SUCH CELL")
    }
    cell.dateLabel.text = entryDate
    cell.textView.text = entryText
    return cell
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    idList = db.textSearch(searchController.searchBar.text ?? "")
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your going to need to show more code. i've never had the issue that it loads at first and then cannot dequeue afterwards, very strange. if its registered, then it's registered. are you using a UISearchController? Only thing I can think of is that you have set `searchResultsController` to another class which hasn't registered the same cell, with the same identifier

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Will need more code/storyboard screenshot potentially. The only thing that springs to mind is if you have set this class to be the datasource for more than one tableview, such that "textcell" is registered for one of them but not the other.

Comment: note: I removed the xcode tag. The issue isn't related to the IDE you are using

Comment: I have posted more of the code, but to be honest, I am not sure where the issue might be. The updateSearchResults was in an extension, but I did worry that the delegation or datasource definition might be an issue, so I moved it into the VC.

Comment: @ces Thanks for the idea, but the view controller is self-contained, one table, one datasource, one cell with that identifier.

Comment: @GntlmnBndt Then assuming that numberOfSections returns 1, numberOfRowsInSection returns idList.count, I can see no other problems. Double-check the case of "textCell" in storyboard (frequently gets me), and that the class is set to TextTableViewCell.

Comment: @ces The numbers are correct. I tried setting the identifier wrong on the storyboard as a test, and the table failed to draw entirely, never getting the chance to tap on search. I am pretty sure it is correct.

Comment: Set a break on the `guard let cell` statement. Run the code fresh and make a note of the id of the tableView. Then tap the search bar and compare the id of the tableView. Make sure it's the same tableView in both cases.